# How can I force an HTTP version in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I have some JavaScript in the browser, and a server that accepts HTTP 1.1 and HTTP 2.

All of my requests default to HTTP 2.

Is there a way to force the use of HTTP 1 in a specific request using JavaScript?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why though?

Comment: I think the only way to do it is via browser configuration, and even that may not be possible.

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem

Comment: I seriously doubt it... but I second Jonas Wilms question as well.  What problem do you expect to solve in this way?

Comment: I allow people to upload multiple files through the browser. When uploading thousands of files in HTTP2 the server gets very slow with all of these concurrent requests.
Rate limiting the endpoint makes excessive requests fail.
If we forced HTTP 1 for that, the browser would only make 5 or 10 of these at a time and handle the delaying of new ones.
This would be much quicker temporary fix than implementing throttling in the browser or server.

Comment: Your title doesn't match what you are asking. You gotta choose which question you wanna see answered.